# Set a grep result into multiple variables

Tags: bash, macos, shell, awk, command-line

I have a script which checks certificates' identities on macOS.

```
security find-identity -v | grep my-cert.test.com
```

The result is:

```
1) 13DB7FSDF188E2C4454KK33E5E0A7B4LK6714658 "my-cert.test.com"
2) 5L56971E29DFA20LHD5E2CEA9DF6J7C46C2D0FD5 "my-cert.test.com"
3) JS34KL78LG620CJKMDFBV5K1K56MNCL9M6SD61L "my-cert.test.com"`
```

Used `awk` to pull just identity

```
security find-identity -v | grep my-cert.test.com | awk '{ print $2}’
```

The result is:

```
13DB7FSDF188E2C4454KK33E5E0A7B4LK6714658 
5L56971E29DFA20LHD5E2CEA9DF6J7C46C2D0FD5 
JS34KL78LG620CJKMDFBV5K1K56MNCL9M6SD61L
```

Which means I have 3 certificates and with `awk` I have separated the rest and just pulled identity with space in between multiple results. Now I want to set the above `grep` result in a variable. If `grep` result is 3 lines, as above, set them in different variables.  I know I can get it into a single variable with `var=$(...)` but I want the results separate.

Example:

```
ONE=13DB7FSDF188E2C4454KK33E5E0A7B4LK6714658
TWO=5L56971E29DFA20LHD5E2CEA9DF6J7C46C2D0FD5
THREE=JS34KL78LG620CJKMDFBV5K1K56MNCL9M6SD61I4
```

and continue if more.

I need this so that I can use those variables in the further script. The `grep` output can be an arbitrary number of lines, 1 or more.

Comment: You could also use `xargs` if you need to process each value on its own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you please try following, you could save `awk`'s result into an array and later you could use that array's values in your program further too. (I removed `grep` from your attempt since `awk` can handle search of string part by itself.)

```
CRT=($(security find-identity -v | awk '/my-cert.test.com/{ print $2}'))
```

Now you could access (all times of array) array named `CRT` by following.

```
count=0
for i in "${CRT[@]}"
do
  echo "CRT["$count"]=$i"
  count=$((count + 1))
done
```

This is why arrays exist - if we need many values of the same kind to be stored separately, but instead of using N number of variables, use an array and access the individual values by array index.

Comment: I am not able to  use veriable  $hostname in `CRT=($(security find-identity -v | awk '/$hostname /{ print $2}'))` in my in can use  `CRT=$(security find-identity -v | grep $hostname | awk '{ print $2}’)` but gives error while using array.

Answer (score 1):

```
set - $CRT; index=0; while [ "$1" ]; do let index=$index+1; eval var${index}="$1"; shift; done
```

This will create variables var1, var2, etc for as many identities you have.

Comment: Though really, an array is almost certainly the better solution.

Comment: Agreed, if your shell supports arrays.